# What's the best way to build an apache flink connector?

Tags: orientdb, apache-flink

I want build flink connector to OrientDB database. I want handle data locality characteristic, whats is the best way to load all data in parallel way in a Dataset? I know that I have to handle the OrientDB way to read data, but, in flink side, wath are the principles and best practices that I have to handle this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to **flink-hbase** connector under **flink-connectors** in [flink source](https://github.com/apache/flink). Basically, you have to implement the interface named **InputFormat** or **RichInputFormat** if you need the **RuntimeContext**.